# Sound don't play when a button is touched in windows phone. (Buttons navigates to next page)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

I am creating application, which use Button to Navigate to another page, and I want to keep sound when user touch the button. The code works fine when there is button only, but when I use button to navigate to another page, the sound didn't play, But play when I press the Back button of Windows phone.

```
public void playSound()
{
    MediaElement playSound1 = new MediaElement();
    playSound1.Source = new Uri("/Sound/Lionsound.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
    playSound1.Play();
}

void btnClassicPuzzle_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    playSound();
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Menu/SelectPack.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: When I remove this part
  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Menu/SelectPack.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
sound plays well.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function to play the sound on the button click and immediately executing the page naviagation. How compiler is processing it is after `playSound1.Play()`, the sound is started and it immediately calls the `NavigationService`. The page is changed and all the objects in the current pages are destroyed therefore, sound stops. What you have to do is navigate to the next page on `MediaEnded` event so it can play complete sound before navigation

```
<MediaElement MediaEnded="eventhandler" ../>
```

[Referenced](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaended%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Also you can check the `MediaPlayer` state by using `MediaPlayer.State`; before navigation

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a globlal MediaElement in your app.

to use a global a global MediaElement you can follow these steps.

First in your app.xaml add a ControlTemplate

```
         <ControlTemplate x:Key="AudioContentTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="MediaElementContainer">

          <!-- The media element used to play sound -->
          <MediaElement Loaded="OnGlobalMediaLoaded"
                        Visibility="Collapsed" />

          <!-- Added for the normal content -->
          <Grid x:Name="ClientArea">
            <ContentPresenter />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
```

Second in your app.xaml.cs  you have to declare the Globlal mediaElement and add methods to play and stop.

```
   private MediaElement globalMediaElement = null;

    private void OnGlobalMediaLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.globalMediaElement == null)
            this.globalMediaElement = sender as MediaElement;

    }


    public   void playMedia(Uri source)
    {
        this.globalMediaElement.Source = source;
        this.globalMediaElement.Play();
    }

    public void stopMedia()
    {
        this.globalMediaElement.Stop();
    }
```

Third in end of app.xaml.cs there is the initialization section and here you injected the    global Mediaelement in the system with the template from the resource:

```
   private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
   {


      RootFrame.Style = (Style)Resources["AudioContentTemplate"];

    }
```

And finally you can call it in your code behind

```
  private void btnClassicPuzzle_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    //play the globlal MediaElement 
     ((App)App.Current).playMedia(new Uri("/Sound/Lionsound.mp3", UriKind.Relative));

      NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Menu/SelectPack.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
   }
```